# Handle "Cancel" subscription on Shopify node/react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, koa-router

I followed the Shopify tutorial to create an embedded app using node.js and react. However, I am facing a problem. If the user "Cancel" the subscription, I need to prevent the user to use the app. I have successfully retrieved the subscription status using a webhook, but I am not able to use it on my index.js to determine if the user has approved or not. The problem is that I cannot use cookies inside a POST request.

```
        ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
        //COOKIES NOT WORKING INSIDE POST - how to retrieve the subscription status in my index.js so
        //I can redirect the user to the subcription url if he didn't accept the subcription ?
        ctx.cookies.set('subscriptionStatus', ctx.state.webhook.payload.app_subscription.status, {
            httpOnly: false,
            sameSite: 'none',
            secure: true
        });

        console.log('received webhook subcription: ', ctx.state.webhook.payload.app_subscription.status);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a cancel webhook in your App, Shopify is giving you the myshopify.com domain name of the store cancelling use of your App. Since your App is receiving the webhook, and since you are storing the name of the shop in your App database, you can simply delete the entry for the shop from your database. That will erase the access token you stored, and hence the person can now not use your App anymore.

Has nothing to do with POST, cookies or anything else really, it is simply you, taking a string, and removing a line from your DB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, do you mean database like postgresql ? I do not store the shop and token in a database. Can you explain further ?